# Estimating Alpha parameter in a stable distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, stable-distribution

I am trying to estimate the alpha parameter of a supposed $\alpha$-stable distributed set of data. I have tried from the Hill estimator to more [advanced fitting method](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25007/fitting-the-parameters-of-a-stable-distribution), but they are or too approximated or too slow for my power of calculation. So after a lot of thinking i have found this way.

I know that in a $\alpha$-stable distribution we have:

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x,\alpha,\beta)\sim -\alpha \gamma^\alpha \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\pi}sin(\frac{\pi \alpha}{2})(1+\beta)x^{-(\alpha+1)}
$$

and

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}P(X>x_0)\sim \gamma^\alpha \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\pi}sin(\frac{\pi \alpha}{2})(1+\beta)x^{-\alpha}
$$

so plotting $P/f$ we must have straight line at x>>1 such that

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{P(X>x_0)}{f(x,\alpha,\beta)}\sim -\frac{x}{\alpha}
$$

and indeed i found a straight line at the tail of every data sample.

Now i have a question:

-because  i found a straight line in the tail of every data sample, is this a general property of distributions?

Comment: thanx, very good, but now i have bigger doubt :( . As i know a normal distribution can be thought as an alpha stable distribution with $\alpha=2$. Why there is such a big difference?

Comment: here: www.webalice.it/marcojl/papers/Thesis.pdf

Comment: It is explicitly stated in the thesis that $\alpha<2$, then there is no contradiction.

Comment: yes you right, but what i means is why there is not a smooth transition from one behaviour to another?

Comment: I guess it is related to the parameterisation. Consider the reparameterisation $\alpha^{\star}=\dfrac{1}{2-\alpha}$. Then $\alpha=2$ corresponds to $\alpha^{\star}=\infty$ which is the "smooth transition" you are looking for.